# What does 算不上 mean in 算不上太美好的日子?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase

This is from the book 我是马拉拉 (the Chinese version of *I am Malala*).

[image: 我是马拉拉 snippet]

I transcribe it to:

> 2012年10月9日，星期二那天发生的事情，改变了一切。那天原本要大考，对学生们来说算不上太美好的日子。但和大多数同学不一样，我号称“小书虫”，感觉考试并不是什么大事。

I translate this to:

> Tuesday, 9-th October 2012.  That day's happenings changed everything.  That day, we originally had a test, with students saying [something? 算不上], it's a beautiful day.  But I'm different to most students, I'm known as "bookworm", I feel a test is not at all a big deal.

**Question**: What does 算不上 mean in this snippet?

Dict.cn translates [算不上](http://dict.cn/%E7%AE%97%E4%B8%8D%E4%B8%8A) to "be not really", so I'm guessing it negates the "it's a beautiful day", so the students think it's "not really a beautiful day" or something like that.  However, I'm not clear on this.  (I think I understand the rest of the snippet.)

Comment: "Be not really" is a good one I think. 对学生们来说算不上太美好的日子 can be "It's not really a very beautiful day to students" or "The day is not really that beautiful to students."

Comment: 美好 here means wonderful, not beautiful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would translate 算不上 to be "cannot count as", so in your context, it would mean "you can't count today as a beautiful day as there is an exam".

Comment: wonderful explanation. 翻译很到位。

Answer (score 3):

Your guess is correct. To be precise, [算不上](http://dict.youdao.com/w/eng/%E7%AE%97%E4%B8%8D%E4%B8%8A/#keyfrom=dict2.index) means *can't be counted ; can't be regarded ; not much*.

So the sentence means *that day can't be regarded as a much beautiful day for students*.

Some other examples.

> 1. 我告诉她以古巴之外的任何标准来衡量，我都算不上一个富有的人。
>    I told her that I was not rich by any standard outside of Cuba.
> 2. 哦，爸爸，如果这还算不上鼓励别人结婚的话，我真不知道什么是鼓励了。
>    Well, papa, if this is not encouragement to marry, I do not know what is.
> 3. 然而，这或许又算不上是新闻，我想大家都知道你会变得很像那些与你一起出去玩的人。
>    Well, maybe it is not a newsflash. I think we all know that you become like those that you hang out with.

Answer (score 2):

Another translation would be "**not exactly**", or "not exactly considered".

The whole sentence would be, "that day was not exactly considered a beautiful day because there was an exam".

Answer (score 1):

If you add the informal tone to it, `算不上太美好` combined is something like `not the best`.

> Tuesday, October 9th 2012, everything changed. An important exam was due,
>   so not the best day for the students. But to me, an exam never felt
>   like a big deal, because unlike others, I am the "bookworm".

Answer (score 0):

算不上   ->    cannot count to be